# Displaying many-to-many using select multiple

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many

right now im building a form that accepts a many to many using a select multiple. after creating the form, im trying to display the information collected in the SHOW page however i dont know how to display that data in embedded ruby. join model is CardTypesList

Models

```
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
self.inheritance_column = nil
validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}

has_many :card_type_lists
has_many :card_types, through: :card_type_lists
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :card_type_lists
end

class CardType < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :card_type_lists
has_many :cards, through: :card_type_lists
end

class CardTypeList < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :cards
belongs_to :card_types
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :card_type
end
```

NEW form using select

```
<%= f.label :types %>
    <%= f.select :card_type_ids, CardTypes.all.collect{|x| [x.name, x.name]}, {},{:title => "Select a Type", :multiple => true, :class => 'selList'} %>
```

Embedded ruby trials

```
<td class="card-td"><%= @card.card_types %></td>
```

Expected: ["Type 1", "Type2"]
this renders the page, but yields (in text):

```
    <ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_CardTypes:0x00000102f58a18>
```

EDIT: schema added.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140120042152) do

  create_table "card_type_lists", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "card_type_id"
    t.integer  "card_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "card_types", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "cards", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "set"
    t.string   "card_types"
    t.string   "colors"
    t.string   "cost"
    t.string   "rarity"
    t.string   "oracle"
    t.float    "value"
    t.integer  "number_owned"
    t.string   "notes"
    t.string   "img_link"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "types_mask"
  end

  add_index "cards", ["name"], name: "index_cards_on_name", unique: true

end
```

and this is my controller:

```
    class CardsController < ApplicationController
  def new
@card = Card.new
    @card.card_type_lists.build.build_card_type
  end

  def show
@card = Card.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @card = Card.new(card_params)
    if @card.save
        redirect_to @card
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def card_params
    params.require(:card).permit(:name, :set, {:card_types => []}, :color, :cost,      :rarity,:oracle,:value, :number_owned,:notes)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be:

```
class CardTypeList < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :card
    belongs_to :card_type #Singular
end
```

---

Some more things to think about:

1. Does your join model have the correct columns?
2. You should use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`
3. Look at how you're calling the data

---

**Schema**

Join models in `has_many :through` have to have `foreign_key` references to both models they're joining. The way you do this is to use a schema like this:

```
card_types_lists
id | card_id | card_type_id | other | information | created_at | updated_at
```

When you mentioned the error `no such column: card_type_lists.card_types_id`, it generally means you either don't have the correct column in the db, or your reference is incorrect. Looking at it, it's your association (referencing plural instead of singular)(fixed above)

---

**Forms**

Something you should consider is using [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) to send the correct data to the nested models

This is when you want to *create* some records in either model, and works by allowing you to define "new" objects for your other models in your parent model, passing the data to your child models, like this:

```
#app/models/card.rb
Class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :card_type_lists
    has_many :card_types, through: :card_type_lists

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :card_type_lists
end

#app/models/card_type_list.rb
Class CardTypeList < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :card
    belongs_to :card_type

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :card_type
end

#app/controllers/cards_controller.rb
def new
    @card = Card.new
    @card.card_types_lists.build.build_card_type
end
```

---

**Data**

If you want to show your associative data correctly, you should try this:

```
#app/views/cards/show.html.erb
<%= @card.card_types %>
```

Comment: i changed the join model to singular, added accepts nested attributes for, and added the build line, but im still getting the uninit constant error.

ive added my schema in my OP, i think my the attribute types might be wrong in the cards table

Comment: so i got the page rendering, but now, however my original question is still hanging. ive tried <%= @card.card_types %> but it just displays the big tag, not the actual array of data im trying to store/display.

Comment: ok so i finally got it! (after making all your suggested changes) my controller needed to change :card_types to :card_type_ids

    def card_params
    params.require(:card).permit(:name, :set, {:card_type_ids => []}, :color, :cost,      :rarity,:oracle,:value, :number_owned,:notes)
    end

then in the embedded ruby SHOW file i did (in embedded tags)

    @card.card_types.each_index do |i|
    @card.card_types[i]["name"]
    end

thanks for your help rick! i may have some issues later when i implement editing but we'll cross that river when we get there haha